# XSLT - write elements from text, then count nodes and add attribute to parent

Tags: csv, xslt, text

I am reading data from a csv file, and adding the result to a table in a file that is a stripped-down version of DITA.

The original DITA file contains, among other things:

```
<para>Put table here.</para>
```

The text input is:

```
row1col1,row1col2,row1col3,row1col4,ro1col5,
row2col1,row2col2,row2col3,,row2col5
row3col1,,row3col3,row3col4,
row4col1,row4col2,,row4col4
```

My attempt at XSLT was this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" doctype-system="myDTD.dtd" />

<!-- use this file on an empty chapter file -->
<!-- make sure the input file is a csv file  -->

    <!-- Edit these parameters if necessary. -->
    <!-- don't forget the single-quote inside double-quote in the select statements below -->
    <xsl:param name="text-encoding" as="xs:string" select="'iso-8859-1'"/>
    <!-- csv file -->
    <xsl:param name="text-uri" as="xs:string" select="'input.csv'"/> <!--change to rename input file-->


<!--Identity template, provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Load csv file as a table -->
    <xsl:template match="para[.='Put table here.']">
        <xsl:element name="table">
            <xsl:attribute name="outputclass">horizontal</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="placement">default</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="tgroup">
                <!--
                <xsl:attribute name="cols">6</xsl:attribute> -->
                <!-- I know the following doesn't work, but to give you an 
                     idea of what I'm looking for - hardcoding as above 
                     works ok. -->
                <xsl:attribute name="cols">
                    <xsl:value-of select="max(count(tbody/row/entry))"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="format">Horizontal</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="tabletitle">Enter title here</xsl:element>

                <xsl:element name="tbody">
                   <xsl:variable name="input" select="unparsed-text($text-uri, $text-encoding)"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($input, '\n')">

                        <xsl:element name="row">
                            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ',')">

                                <xsl:element name="entry">
                                    <xsl:element name="para">
                                        <xsl:value-of select=". "/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:element>

                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:element>

                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>

            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces this output, (in part), which is almost what I want:

```
                <table outputclass="horizontal" placement="default">
                    <tgroup cols="0" format="Horizontal">
                        <tabletitle>Enter title here</tabletitle>
                        <tbody>
                            <row>
                                <entry>
                                    <para>row1col1</para>
                                </entry>
                                <entry>
                                    <para>row1col2</para>
                                </entry>
                                <entry>
                                    <para>row1col3</para>
                                </entry>
                                <entry>
                                    <para>row1col4</para>
                                </entry>
                                <entry>
                                    <para>ro1col5</para>
                                </entry>
                                <entry>
                                    <para>
</para>
                                </entry>
                            </row>
```

....... etc....

Except of course, I want the

```
<tgroup cols="0" >
```

tag to be

```
<tgroup cols="6"  >
```

If I hardcode the 6, I get what I want. Is there a way to do this dynamically?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're in XSLT 2.0 you *can* do this by storing the table markup in a variable, then calculating the cols number before you send it all to the output.

```
            <xsl:element name="tgroup">

              <xsl:variable name="table">
                <xsl:element name="tabletitle">Enter title here</xsl:element>

                <xsl:element name="tbody">
                   <xsl:variable name="input" select="unparsed-text($text-uri, $text-encoding)"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($input, '\n')">

                        <xsl:element name="row">
                            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ',')">

                                <xsl:element name="entry">
                                    <xsl:element name="para">
                                        <xsl:value-of select=". "/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:element>

                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:element>

                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:variable>

              <xsl:attribute name="cols">
                <xsl:value-of select="max($table/tbody/row/count(entry))"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="format">Horizontal</xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:sequence select="$table/*" />
            </xsl:element>
```

Note the change I've made to your `max` expression - your original approach of

```
max(count($table/tbody/row/entry))
```

will not work, because `count(tbody/row/entry)` is a single number, the total number of entry elements across all the rows in the table.  Instead you need

```
max($table/tbody/row/count(entry))
```

which creates a *sequence* of numbers (one for each row, the number being the count of entries in just that row) and then finds the highest number in that sequence.

---

As an aside, you may find it more readable if you used literal result elements rather than `xsl:element` when you have fixed element names:

```
            <xsl:variable name="table">
                <tabletitle>Enter title here</tabletitle>

                <tbody>
                   <xsl:variable name="input" select="unparsed-text($text-uri, $text-encoding)"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($input, '\n')">

                        <row>
                            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ',')">

                                <entry>
                                    <para>
                                        <xsl:value-of select=". "/>
                                    </para>
                                </entry>

                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </row>

                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tbody>
            </xsl:variable>

            <tgroup cols="{max($table/tbody/row/count(entry))}" format="Horizontal">
              <xsl:sequence select="$table/*" />
            </tgroup>
```

Comment: Excellent help, thanks. xsl:variable and xsl:sequence. The literal elements are also a good idea. Now it works a charm.

Comment: @rawtext I've added an edit to draw attention to arguably the most important part of the answer - how to actually calculate the maximum row length.